# How to find an element in Scene Builder by its fx:id

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, scenebuilder

In Scene Builder I'm getting an warning every time I open a .fxml file. The warning says:

> Duplicate usage of fx:id="x2"

I don't remember to have set an `fx:id` of `x2` to any element, but this is not really a problem. The problem is that I have hundreds of elements in several different containers and it's very hard to find this two elements with this `fx:id` to fix this warning.

Is there a way I can find an element in Scene Builder by searching it by its `fx:id`?

**EDIT**

The element with duplicated id was an [Insets](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/geometry/Insets.html), I'm not sure how it is created, but I'm sure that it's not visible neither in the Library area, nor in the Hierarchy area, nor in the main area of the Scene Builder. Their ids were duplicated somehow when I copied and pasted an HBox with an Label and a Button inside. The ids of the HBox, Label and Button weren't duplicated, just the Insets' id was.

The Insets looks like this in the source code:

```
<HBox.margin>
    <Insets left="130.0" fx:id="x2" />
</HBox.margin>
```

I just removed their id and the problem was gone! Antoniossss' answer helped me.

Comment: probably a bug in scene builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just simply edit your generated `fxml` file with text editor and search for `x2` in it?

Comment: What a simple and great idea! I completely forgot the source code and was looking only in the visual tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try the below to get the element by id

```
scene.lookup("#yourid");
```

Comment: Where should I write this?

Comment: after the scene has rendered.